# If i update to ionic 2 can i still use ionic 1

Tags: ionic-framework, updates

If I update my version of ionic to version 2 can i still use version 1.7.14 in my code?

Will it mess anything up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still work with ionic 1 code and everything will work without problems